# Istio Kubernetes - Version compatibility

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Is there a compatibility mapping Istio - Kubernetes - couldn't find one.
Istio 1.7 release notes mention needs K8s 1.16+, but nothing with Istio 1.6 or Istio 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Support status of Istio releases](https://istio.io/latest/about/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases) is what you looking for.
[image]

For istio 1.9 you can use [Istio Prelim 1.9 website](https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/)

> These steps require you to have a cluster running a compatible version
> of Kubernetes (**1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19**). You can use any supported
> platform, for example Minikube or others specified by the
> platform-specific setup instructions.

Comment: Thx, Google will not find this for me

Comment: Vit. It seems (from a now deleted answer by other user) that the info has changed. Would you like to update?